# build slider using jquery & javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I built slider using jquery but it is very stupid. You can see it:
http://jsfiddle.net/Bf2Mv/
i think the problem is here:

```
$(".img img").fadeOut().attr("src", images[count % images.length]).fadeIn();
$(".text").fadeOut().html(text[textcount % text.length]).fadeIn();
```

how to fix the effects?
thanks a lot!

Comment: `"it is very stupid"` is not a very good description of a problem :) Please explain what you do not like and what it should do instead. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted something like this:

### JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/Bf2Mv/7/

```
    count = 0,
    text = [
        "first img desc",
        "2nd img desc",
        "3rd img desc"],
    imageCount = images.length,
    rand = 6000;

    function slide() {
        changeImage(1)
        rand = 6000;
    }

    function changeImage(delta) {
        count += delta;
        if (count < 0) count = imageCount - 1;
        count %= imageCount;
        $(".img img").fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).attr("src", images[count]).fadeIn()
        });
        $(".text").fadeOut(function () {
            $(this).html(text[count]).fadeIn();
        });
    }

    (function loop() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            slide();
            loop();
        }, rand);
    }());

    $("#next").click(function () {
        changeImage(1);
    });

    $("#prev").click(function () {
        changeImage(-1);
    });
```

### Notes:

1. You only need a single counter if the images and text arrays are the same length.
2. You did not need to have modulus operators everywhere if the indexes are managed correctly (between 0 and length-1)
3. You need to correctly wrap around from `0` to `length-1` and back the other way.
4. You need to change the images after they fadeout (hence the new callbacks in fadeout)
5. I refactored the change code, so it just takes a direction delta value. That way the same code can be reused by the timer, the next and the prev options.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was on how the fadein/fadeout was defined. You need to use the jQuery fadein/fadeout finished parameter function.

```
$(".img img").stop().fadeOut('fast', function() {
    var that = $(this);
    that.attr("src", images[count]).fadeIn('fast', function() {
        if (!LOOP_INTERVAL) {                
            startLoop(); // Continue the loop.
        }
    });        
});
```

There were also some other issues on the indexes. Here's the solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Bf2Mv/45/

I hope this is what you meant. If you have questions about the answer, feel free to ask!